# gnome language selector refuses to set language

Tags: language-support

When I run `gnome-language-selector` as my normal user, I get the following output upon dragging and dropping a new language above the default english.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/LanguageSelector/LocaleInfo.py:124: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if lang_name == self._lang[lang]:
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Ikke tilgang
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Ikke tilgang
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Ikke tilgang
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Ikke tilgang
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/LanguageSelector/gtk/GtkLanguageSelector.py", line 62, in wrapper
    res = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/LanguageSelector/gtk/GtkLanguageSelector.py", line 1047, in on_treeview_locales_drag_end
    self.writeUserLanguage(envLanguage)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/LanguageSelector/gtk/GtkLanguageSelector.py", line 800, in writeUserLanguage
    self.writeUserLanguageSetting(userLanguage=languageString)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/LanguageSelector/LanguageSelector.py", line 83, in writeUserLanguageSetting
    iface.SetLanguage(userLanguage)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.Accounts.Error.Failed: not access to HOME yet so language not saved
(Ikke tilgang -> not allowed)
```

I said, okay, that seems like a permissions problem. So i re-run it as root and have the following error:

```
$ sudo gnome-language-selector 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/LanguageSelector/LocaleInfo.py:124: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if lang_name == self._lang[lang]:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/LanguageSelector/LanguageSelector.py:77: UserWarning: No language saved for user 'root'.
  warnings.warn("No language saved for user '%s'." % os.getenv('USER'))
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this? Or what I could do to debug/fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The cause was a missing `.profile` file in my home directory.

Solution: Open a terminal and run the following command in it:

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/
```

Then change the language in gnome-language-selector.

See [bug 1018621](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/1018621) for more info.

If the above solution doesn't work for you, try to search the web for that unicode warning (lines 1-2) or those debconf warnings (lines 3-6).  I didn't have those warnings.